# How to do namespacing in Browserify and Javascript

Tags: javascript, namespaces, browserify

```
   var exports = module.exports = {};
var base_url = "https://something.com:4242/";
exports.ordersummaryurl =base_url +"v1/api/stats?domain=order";
```

How do i do namespacing in the above code so that it has the below structure

```
urls.order.summary
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript does not really have a "namespace" the same way other languages such as c# does.

[How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript)

Taken from that link: the best way to get the functionality that you are describing is to encapsulate the data like such:

```
var urls = {
    order: {
        summary: "asdfasdfasdf"
    },

    foo: function() {
    },

    bar: function() {
    }
};
```

To add on to this: keeping your functions in separate files and only including the "modules" that you need is another common way of achieving this.